# Mocking object from another class

Tags: junit, mocking

I have a service class that starts a service.
This service should only start between a certain time.
So i need to mock this , but it does not work.

My Time class:

```
public  boolean isTimeBetween_00_06(){
     return Instant.now().isBefore(Instant.now()
    .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
    .plus(6,ChronoUnit.HOURS));
}
```

My Service class:

```
start(){
    if(! new MyTimeUtils().isTimeBetween_00_06){
        throw new Exception;
    }

}
```

My test class:

```
@InjectMocks
private MyServiceClass service;

@Mock
private MyTimeUtils myTimeUtils;

@Test
myTest(){

Mockito.when(myTimeUtils.isCurrentTimeBetween_00_06()).thenReturn(true);

service.start();

}
```

I expect that I get the right assert, but it stops with Exption.

I also tryed PowerMockito but still it did not work.

Someone have an idea?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should inject `MyTimeUtils` instead of instance creation in the method.
And don't forget `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`;

Have a look at the code, please:

```
public class MyServiceClass {
    private final MyTimeUtils myTimeUtils;

    public MyServiceClass(MyTimeUtils myTimeUtils) {
        this.myTimeUtils = myTimeUtils;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (!myTimeUtils.isTimeBetween_00_06()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ERROR");
        }
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceClassTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private MyServiceClass service;

    @Mock
    private MyTimeUtils myTimeUtils;

    @Test
    public void myTest(){
        Mockito.when(myTimeUtils.isTimeBetween_00_06()).thenReturn(true);

        service.start();
    }
}
```